# Clean a pandas Series: for each row, if string is in values (values=list or set) of dictionary, replace with key

Tags: pandas, dictionary, data-cleaning

I have a book that I have broken down into dialogue for each character, however I noticed there are many typos and different names for the same characters. I created a dictionary hoping to associate each alias back to the proper character, but I am having trouble executing. Here is my Pandas Series and desired output:

```
Narrator ---> Output

Robert -----> Robert
Dan    -----> Dan
Daniel -----> Daniel
Robbie -----> Robert
Rob    -----> Robert
Jacob  -----> Jacob
```

And my dictionary is as follows:

```
char_dict = {'Robert': ['Robert', 'Robbie', 'Rob'],
             'Daniel': ['Daniel', 'Dan']}
```

1. If the string is in a list of values in the dictionary, how would I replace it with the key. Do I need to reverse my dictionary?
2. Can I do this same operation with a set instead of the list in my dictionary?

   char_dict = {'Robert': {'Robert', 'Robbie', 'Rob'},
                'Daniel': {'Daniel', 'Dan'}}

I have used this code, which actually does get me a working output, but it is very difficult to quickly look at and understand which names are associated with which character. Is there a more efficient method?

```
new_char_dict = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in char_dict.items() for k in oldv}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I would just reverse the dict:

```
rev = {c:k for k, v in char_dict.items() for c in v}
```

This dictionary comprehension will work if the original dictionary values are lists or sets (or tuples).

And then map that to the column:

```
df["Output"] = df["Narrator"].map(rev)
```

This seems like the most efficient approach to me. But if your primary concern is making the code as human-readable as possible, then you could break down the dictionary comprehension into a standard for loop:

```
alias_to_name = dict()
for char_name, list_of_aliases in char_dict.items():
    for char_alias in list_of_aliases:
        alias_to_name[char_alias] = char_name

df["Output"] = df["Narrator"].map(alias_to_name)
```

But this is just doing the same thing in-I would argue-less elegant code.